# Link two select inputs in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to link two select inputs, so when I change one the other will change based on the selected value in the first select input.

I used `ng-options` for that, as following :

**first select :**

```
ng-options="region.codeRegion as region.nomRegion for region in regions"
```

**second select :**

```
ng-options="province.codeProvince as province.nomProvince for province in candidature.resident.eps.region.provinces track by province.codeProvince"
```

for the data I'm using you can find it in the plunker below.

the first select is working but the second didn't work.

Here is a plunker for it : http://plnkr.co/edit/HLCIw099H4UYkGg4s78h?p=preview

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 3):

You should have `ng-model="selectedRegion` on your first select, and on the second select list options based on `selectedRegion`.

```
<select ng-options="region.nomRegion for region in regions" ng-model="selectedRegion"></select>                   

<select ng-options="province.codeProvince for province in  selectedRegion.provinces track by province.codeProvince"  ng-model="candidature.resident.eps.province"></select>
```

Here is the [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rrfUDI12XyyH1OQdm948?p=preview)